# laravel mongodb how to change _id to id on output?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I want to have `_id` in the database but want to output `id` when doing a query.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (using an Accessor) :

**Model**

```
public function getIdAttribute() {
      return $this->attributes['_id'];
}
```

**Controller test**

```
$user = User::find(1);
// this will call getIdAttribute which will return the `_id`
dd($user->id);
```

> You can also override toArray() method if you want to show it :

**Model**

```
// ..
// getIdAttribute()
// ..
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $array['id'] = $this->id;
    unset($array['_id']);
    return $array;
}
```

**Controller Test**

```
$user = User::find(1);
dd($user->toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is using Transformers (http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/). There is a service provider for Laravel here (https://github.com/gathercontent/laravel-fractal).
It will do that in a elegant way :)

Of course, if you need to do only with "id" field, I'll do like zorx told:

`public function getIdAttribute() {
      return $this->attributes['_id'];
}`

But you'll probably put that in some BaseModel or abstractModel class, a parent for you models who need this.